# How to replace all occurrence of all substring having special character with another substring according to dictionary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a large string like this one -: 
`str = "$a + $b + $a + $c?$a$c$c....."` 
and a Dictionary object -:

`{ "$a": '2',  "$b": '3', "$c":'4',....}` i.e keys are all the substring start with '$'

What is the best and fastest approach to replace all occurrence of keys in dictionary with their corresponding value??

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace()`

```js
const data = {"$a": '2', "$b": '3', "$c":'4'}

const str = "$a + $b + $a + $c?$a$c$c....."

const res = str.replace(/\$\w+\b/g, match => data[match])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work when string have some other substring start with $ but no in dictionary
eg -:
`const data = {"$a": '2', "$b": '3', "$c":'4'}`
`const str = "$a + $b + $a + $c?$a$c$c$d"`  Here i do not want to change $d.
but your solution output this -: `2 + 3 + 2 + 4?244undefined`

Comment: should i need to use something other than dictionary,  if yes any suggestion??

Comment: Just try `data[match] || ''`

Comment: actually i want this answer -:
`2 + 3 + 2 + 4?244$d`  i.e do not want to modify other substrings
but it will return this
`2 + 3 + 2 + 4?244`

Comment: @AmanGupta `data[match] || match`. please question properly what you need. and atleast give a try